# vue.js show component after jquery ajax

Tags: vue.js

I have some components. After a jquery AJAX request i would show a specific component. Is there a function for that?

```
<comp1 :page="page1"></comp1>
<comp2 :page="page2"></comp1>
<comp3 :page="page3"></comp1>
```

The AJAX is in a another file.

Comment: Please add more details on what needs to be done, what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `Conditional Rendering` with the help of [v-if](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html) or [v-show](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-show) directive:

using v-show:

```
<comp1 :page="page1" v-show="showComp1"></comp1>
```

using v-if:

```
<comp1 :page="page1" v-if="showComp1"></comp1>
```

You can set these `data` variables `showComp1`, `showComp2` and others depending on the response of AJAX call, depending on which corresponding components will be rendered in the view.

---

[v-if vs v-show](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if-vs-v-show)

> v-if is “real” conditional rendering because it ensures that event
> listeners and child components inside the conditional block are
> properly destroyed and re-created during toggles.
>
> v-if is also lazy:
> if the condition is false on initial render, it will not do anything -
> the conditional block won’t be rendered until the condition becomes
> true for the first time.
>
> In comparison, v-show is much simpler - the
> element is always rendered regardless of initial condition, with just
> simple CSS-based toggling.
>
> Generally speaking, v-if has higher toggle
> costs while v-show has higher initial render costs. So prefer v-show
> if you need to toggle something very often, and prefer v-if if the
> condition is unlikely to change at runtime.

Comment: The v-if attribute looks like v-if="page=='start'". Is that correct or rather it means something else?

Comment: @timmy v-if takes a variable, which it evaluates to true or false and decides whether to render it or not. `v-if="page=='start'"` is also valid, if value of page is "start", corresponding element will be rendered.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `v-show` for that, and just bind each component to a flag stored in `data`:

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  methods: {
     makeCall(){
        this.$http.get('foo')
          .then(response => {
             // after ajax call set comp1 show flag to true
             this.show.comp1 = true;
         });
     }
  },
  data: {
    show: {
      comp1: false,
      comp2: true,
      comp3: false
    }
  }
});
```

Then just bind them with `v-show` like so:

```
  <comp1 v-show="show.comp1"></comp1>
  <comp2 v-show="show.comp2"></comp2>
  <comp3 v-show="show.comp3"></comp3>
```

here's a JSFiddle to show you how it works: https://jsfiddle.net/wp5tfe2e/